# How do you prevent Xcode 7 Playgrounds from automatically running?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, refresh, swift-playground

I'm working on an Xcode 7 Playground that has many things running at once. Whenever I make an edit, it refreshes, restarts what was running and runs through the entire code again. That crashes my playground around every 15 minutes. Is there a way to prevent playgrounds from automatically running whenever I make an edit?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

In the lower-left part of the Playground there's a right-facing blue arrow, looking like a "play" button.

Do a long click on this button and you will get two options: "Automatically Run" and "Manually Run".

Choose the latter to put the Playground is manual mode and start/stop its execution yourself by clicking on this button.

[image]

---

You can also trigger the code execution by making a custom shortcut to the "Execute Playground" Editor menu command.

Go to `Xcode > Preferences...` then go to `Key Bindings`, scroll down to `Editor Menu for Playground` and add a new shortcut of your choice by double-clicking in the right column in front of the `Execute Playground` command.

[image]

Comment: Wish there was a shortcut key combination for this as Cmd+R for running an app in regular Xcode mode

Comment: @PaulGurov I've edited my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: @PavelGurov See my answer using macOS shortcuts

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know of a way to make this a default for new playgrounds, would you? Automatic execution has been the source of much frustration for me (mostly since it kills my CPU) and I would love to disable it once instead of every time I create a new playground.

Answer (score 12):

**Actually, you CAN map a shortcut for "Execute Playground" to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.**

Use macOS keyboard shortcuts, instead of Xcode's keybindings.

Go to `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts`,

and in `App shortcuts`, click on `+`.

Choose `Xcode.app`, and add a new shortcut for "Execute Playground" (you have to type precisely this!).
[image: Shortcuts 1]

Then click on `Add`.
[image: Shortcuts 2]

Now you can use this shortcut in Xcode.
[image: Xcode menu shortcut]

And don't worry for conflicts (at least up to Xcode 9): `Execute Playground` is not available for standard Xcode projects, and `Run` is not active for Playgrounds.